# react-custom-scrollbars dynamic content scroll

Tags: reactjs

I have been using [react-custom-scrollbars](https://github.com/malte-wessel/react-custom-scrollbars) for custom scrolling in my app, there comes a point, the data would be dynamic and scroll should go to bottom or recent data added.

simple react-custom-scrollbar looks like below:

```
import { Scrollbars } from 'react-custom-scrollbars';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Scrollbars style={{ width: 500, height: 300 }}>
        <p>Some great content...</p>
      </Scrollbars>
    );
  }
}
```

above code works fine, In my case the content `<p>Some great content...</p>` is dynamic.

tried adding dynamic data and done with it, the real problem occurred in scroll. The scroll should go to an element added recently, and it worked but it stopped working the native scroll functionality after that.

You can see the entire code [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-mnvpyc)

updated a gif of issue: [image]

Any help on this really appreciated.

Comment: That seems to work as desired?

Comment: hope you checked the demo code, scroll goes bottom when data added, but you need to scroll top to see previous data's. when you scroll up you can see that scroll have glitches

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The code [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-obxt43?file=Hello.js) has no glitches in scrolling.

Comment: got solution by moving  this.customRef.scrollToBottom(); from componentDidUpdate to loadMore() function where content will be populated on click.

Comment: Jayavel can you expand on this? I am using the component in the same way and I have an issue where the scroll bar jumps to the top of the page whenever I take some action on the page. Would greatly appreciate some help!

Comment: can you upload your fiddle/stackblitz, so that I can see what went wrong !